# How to register more than one button tap using UIKit in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am experimenting with buttons, and I have run into what is probably a simple problem. I have two buttons and two labels.

The labels generate random string values of either "A" or "B". I want the correct label to disappear if the appropriate button is selected.

I have come up with the following code, but I have run into a problem. If the letters are the same, both labels will be hidden when the corresponding button is tapped.

I understand why this is happening, I think. It's because my code is executed when buttonA is tapped once(I haven't started on button B yet, so it doesn't do anything.)

So my question is how do I require 2 taps? In other words, if label_1 and label_2 are both displayed as String "A", how would i require the user to tap buttonA twice? If more code is needed, let me know in the comments.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var label_1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label_2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label_3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label_4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label_5: UILabel!


    var visibleLetters = ["A", "B", "Z", "X"]
    var text = "", text2 = "", text3 = "", text4 = "", text5 = ""
    let aButton = "A", bButton = "B", zButton = "Z", xButton = "X"
    var x = 0


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        createRandomLetter(text, aSecondLetter: text2, aThirdLetter: text3, aFourthLetter: text4, aFifthLetter: text5)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonA(sender: UIButton) {

        if aButton == label_1.text {
            label_1.hidden = true
            label_1.tag += 1
        }

        else {
            //play animation
            print("play animation")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonB(sender: UIButton) {
        if bButton == label_1.text {
            label_1.hidden = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonX(sender: UIButton) {
        if xButton == label_1.text {
            label_1.hidden = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonZ(sender: UIButton) {
        if zButton == label_1.text {
            label_1.hidden = true
        }
    }



    func createRandomLetter(individualLetter: String, aSecondLetter: String, aThirdLetter: String, aFourthLetter: String, aFifthLetter: String) {

        let individuaLetter = visibleLetters[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(visibleLetters.count)))],
        aSecondLetter = visibleLetters[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(visibleLetters.count)))],
        aThirdLetter = visibleLetters[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(visibleLetters.count)))],
        aFourthLetter = visibleLetters[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(visibleLetters.count)))],
        aFifthLetter = visibleLetters[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(visibleLetters.count)))]

        label_1.text = individuaLetter
        label_2.text = aSecondLetter
        label_3.text = aThirdLetter
        label_4.text = aFourthLetter
        label_5.text = aFifthLetter
    }

    func isCorrect() {

        if aButton == label_1.text {
            label_1.hidden = true
            label_1.tag += 1
        }

        else if label_1.tag == 1 && aButton == label_2.text {

        }
        else {
            //play animation
            print("play animation")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. Can you give me more detail?

Comment: Is label1 tied to buttonA and label2 tied to buttonB? Can you explain the need to two taps.

Comment: I'll do my best to explain what I want. I have a random set of letters and a constant set of buttons. The buttons are always  A, B, X, Z(I regret adding the extra buttons so soon), so I'm going to pretend like I didn't add X and Z. So I have 2 labels that randomly display A or B. The user has to press A if label_1 is showing A, or B if label_1 is showing B. If the user presses the correct button, then he does the same for label_2.

Comment: @ryantxr Perhaps the multiple taps was misleading. What I want to check is if the corresponding button and label match. For instance, buttonA and label_1, to basically repeat the process for button A or B with label_2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK trying to figure it out what you are trying to do let's do an example. So  you have 4 labels, and 2 Buttons (A,B), the labels have random generated values of A,B when you click a button you need to check if that button has the same text of the label then if it is correct we do the same with label2 if it's not correct we keep trying.

A logical way to do this can be to associate tags to your labels (that i think you are alredy doing it) and  have a temporal variable to keep track of the current label for example

```
  var temporal:String!
  var current_tag:Int = 1
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createRandomLetter(text, aSecondLetter: text2,
    aThirdLetter: text3, aFourthLetter: text4, aFifthLetter: text5)
     temporal = label1.text

}

  @IBAction func buttonZ(sender: UIButton) {
    //Answer is correct 
    if zButton == temporal {
        current_tag++
        IsCorrect(current_tag)
    }

}
func Iscorrect(tag:Int)
{

   if(label2.tag == tag)
   {
        temporal = label2.text
   }
   else if(label3.tag == tag)
   {
        temporal = label2.text
   }
   else if(label4.tag == tag)
   {
        temporal = label2.text
   }
}
```

Somethign like that should work, I didn't try it as I'm answering from my Ipad and I do not have access to my laptop but something like that should totally work, any doubt I can help you XD

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I am trying to do! Now I'm trying to understand why it works. Also, I get this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. I figured I received the error because label2.tag wasn't matching with current_tag, but they seem to match up, so I'm trying to figure out why temporal doesn't have a value.

Comment: that error must have happen cause when we are trying to compare a variable that has not been asigned, that why in the view didload method I initialized temporal try to initialize before to something like  var temporal:String = ""     I will be at home in a couple of hours to try it out please if answer helped you mark it as correct XD

Comment: I missed that you assigned the variable in the viewDidLoad. After working on it for awhile, I think I got the basic idea as to what is happening. Thank you for your help.

Comment: any doubt we are here for help XD